# Celery gossip to implement a distributed task lock

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

If I wish to have only one task of a specific type run at a time, there are enough examples that suggest that django cache may be used for it. Now that celery gossip has worker-worker communication, is there a way a distributed lock may be generated to check if a specific type of task is being processed, the current task be rescheduled? Or, if multiple tasks of same type come to different workers, then only one should get processed and others get requeued.

I do not want any dependency on cache (mem/db) for locking operation, so wish to know if anyone has thoughts on similar lines.

Comment: Redis works really well as a distributed task lock.

Comment: Yes it does, but I was wondering if workers can communicate, then a lock may be implemented without needing any support of any other entity (like Redis).